# what does the dev key represent in the object returned by fs.Stat with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Below is the object I'm referring to - I'm trying to figure out what the `dev` key means (the very first key value pair). I was reading this from the following link: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

```
Stats {
    dev: 2114,
    ino: 48064969,
    mode: 33188,
    nlink: 1,
    uid: 85,
    gid: 100,
    rdev: 0,
    size: 527,
    blksize: 4096,
    blocks: 8,
    atimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
    mtimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
    ctimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
    birthtimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
    atime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
    mtime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
    ctime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
    birthtime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fs.stat` is an async [`stat(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) call.

Based on the above [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html):

> st_dev
>   This field describes the device on which this file resides.
>   (The major(3) and minor(3) macros may be useful to decompose the device ID in this field.)